# Make google index the actual image not the thumbnail

Tags: seo, images, image-search, google-image-search

In a website, we have a JavaScript that opens an image when people click on the thumbnail, it seems like Google only indexes the thumbnail not the actual image with real dimensions, I was wondering if there is a way to tell Google where the actual image is and guide Google on what images to pick for `images.google.com`

**Any thoughts on that?**

Comment: Does the thumbnail actually link directly to the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try creating an image sitemap http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
 <url>
   <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
   <image:image>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
   </image:image>
   <image:image>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
   </image:image>
 </url> 
</urlset>
```

Comment: further, if you don't want google to index the thumbnail at all - and only index the real picture you can use 301 redirect (from the thumbnail to the *real** picture): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322454/syntax-for-301-redirect-of-www-to-non-www-using-httpd-conf

Comment: @alfasin: The StackOverflow question you link to is about redirecting all `www` requests to `non-www` - which is quite different. What do users see when thumbnails are redirected to the larger image? Or do you intend to only target the Googlebot?!

Comment: @w3d the link only shows an example of usage of redirect 301 which can be used not only for redirecting www to non-www. When you use 301 redirect google will index the target - not the source.

Comment: @alfasin: But if you simply 301 redirect then no-one can see the thumbnail. If you specifically check for the Googlebot (and other search engines) then this is a form of [cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) which _could_ count against you. So I'm wondering whether this could be a risky practise?

Comment: @w3d You're right, a better practice will be to use "Demote sitelink URL" feature in Google Webmasters.

Comment: @alfasin: Unfortunately "[sitelinks](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334)" are something different. I don't think the same tool can be used to demote images in Image Search.

Comment: @w3d do you think it "treats" differently images and "regular" URL ?

Comment: @alfasin: But "sitelinks" are not "regular" URLs either. _Sitelinks_ are the secondary links that appear below some results in Google Search (not Image Search) to help users navigate your site. The "Demote this sitelink URL" feature is for these specific links only.